# Vertically and horizontally centering text within a div

Tags: css

I have a div that comprises a graphic background overlaid with text. I want to center this element horizontally and vertically. But I can't get the text to center vertically. So far, I have the following code:

```
<div id="step">
    <div id="background">
        <img src="buttonbackground.png" class="stretch" alt="" />
    </div>
    <div>
       <h3>some text</h3>
    </div>
</div>
```

In the CSS:

```
#background {
    width: 100%; 
    height: 100%; 
    position: absolute; 
    left: 0px;
    z-index: -1;
}

#step {
    text-align:center;
    color:white;
}

.stretch {
    width:200px;
    height:40px;
}
```

Using the table-cell/vertical-align technique I've seen often referenced elsewhere doesn't quite work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Given that it's an `H3` i'm assuming it's a heading so it's probably gonna be one line of text. If that's the case just set the `line-height`of the `h3`to the height of the container.

If instead it's a paragraph you can do this:

```
#centeredDiv {
  position:absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%
  margin-top:-20px ;(half the height of the container)
  margin-left: -100px; (half the width of the container)
```

}

Don't mix pixels with percentages.

Answer (score 3):

Try:

```
#step {
    text-align: center;
    vertical-align: center;
    color: white;
    height: 40px;
}
```

EDIT:

Alternatively, you could try explicitly setting the height of #background to 40px instead of 100%. It should achieve the same effect.